# Is it possible to add description to cisco ACL?

Tags: cisco, access-control-list

I would like to add a description to cisco ACL.
Something like: 
Permit all traffic from the R&D depatment to the lab. or 
Deny traffic from HA to R&D.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

This is standard ip ACL syntax:

For named ACLs.

```
ip access-list {standard|extended} access-list-name
remark This is a comment
```

For numbered ACLs:

```
access-list 101 remark permit_telnet
```

Source: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/ios-firewall/23602-confaccesslists.html#comments